# Android Studio MDC couldn't display correctly on Preview

Tags: android, android-studio

When I was using the Material Components, I suddenly found that the FloatingActionButton of Preview changed from a circle to a square and the following error was reported. I didn't find a similar situation, and after using Git to roll back to the previous version, this problem still exists, it seems For example, Android Studio can't recognize the Material theme, but it has always been recognized before.

Such as:
it diplays correctly on my device as a circle

[uncorrect style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2vZa.png)

[correct style on the device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRToO.png)

[warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wSqp.png)

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant).
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:243)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:213)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:148)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:76)
    at com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:212)
    at com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:201)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:339)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:176)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:136)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:301)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:417)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:428)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:332)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:363)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:436)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:121)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:739)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$8(RenderTask.java:895)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:187)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I try to "clean -> rebuild", "Invadiate restart", Update AS to newest version, but it doesn't work.

AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <style name="Theme.Base" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/HH_BandColor_1</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/HH_BandColor_1</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">true</item>
<!--        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/white</item>-->
    </style>
    <style name="TabRadioButton_center">
        <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:button">@null</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/GrayScale_100</item>
    </style>
    <style name="TabRadioButton_left">
        <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">left</item>
        <item name="android:button">@null</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/GrayScale_100</item>
    </style>
    <declare-styleable name="MaxHeightRecyclerView">
        <attr name="maxHeight" format="dimension" />
    </declare-styleable>
<!--    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"></style>-->


</resources>
```

gradle version: 7.0.2
material version: 1.3.0

Thanks for giving me a advice. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity)

Comment: It doesn't work, actually I've checked all the Theme xml but nothing worked